# Address of array element in binary

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

In my mips code, I create an array of 2 elements:

```
  .data

myArray: .word 1, 2
```

Using qtspim, under the User data segment section, the address of the first element will be shown in square brackets. Let's say that the first element of the array is in address 10010000. As each word is a 4 bytes, am I correct to say that the next element in the array is in address 10010004?

Comment: _"Let's say that the first element of the array is in address 10010000. As each word is a 4 bytes, am I correct to say that the next element in the array is in address 10010004?"_ Yes.

Comment: Is 10010000 a binary number? (As indicated in the title?) Then the address of the next element is 10010100.